# conectar a socket server de nodejs de manera remota en ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, socket.io, ionic4

Me encontraba usando:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

en mi proyecto de ionic, y requeria asegurarme de que la conexion mediante dispositivos moviles tambien funcionara de manera correcta, sin embargo, cuando corro el socket server de nodejs y conecto un cliente al server, en la laptop funciona de manera correcta, es decir, puedo tener tantos clientes conectados como se requiera y funciona de manera correcta, pero cuando trato de hacer funcionar este mismo socket server pero mediante un dispositivo movil como por ejemplo un android (El dispositivo real, ninguno emulado), e intento conectarme al socket server, no me aparece ningun mensaje de error del lado del servidor, pero tampoco me realiza la conexion, del lado del cliente no me da ningún error tampoco cuando lo inspecciono conectado por medio de:

chrome://inspect

este seria el socket server creado en nodejs:

```
const app = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
let usersConnections = [];

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{

    console.log("connection received!");
    socket.on('disconnect', ()=>{

        for(let i = 0; i < usersConnections.length; i++){

            if(
                usersConnections[i]["ID"] == socket.id && 
                usersConnections[i]["username"] == socket.nickname && 
                usersConnections[i]["type_user"] == socket.type_user
            ){
                usersConnections.splice(i, 1);
                io.emit('users-changed', {
                    user: socket.nickname,
                    index: i - 1,
                    type_user: socket.type_user, 
                    event: 'left'
                });
                console.log(usersConnections);
                console.log("\n\n");
            }

        }

    });

    socket.on('set-nickname', (data)=>{

        socket.nickname = data.nickname;
        socket.type_user = data.type_user;
        socket.location = data.location;
        usersConnections.push(
            {ID: socket.id, username: data.nickname, type_user: data.type_user, location: data.location}
        );

        socket.broadcast.emit(
            'users-changed', 
            {
                name: data.nickname, 
                src: data.src,
                description: data.description,
                isChecked: false,
                location: data.location, 
                event: 'joined'
            }
        );
        console.log(usersConnections);

    });

    socket.on('send-invitation', (data)=>{

        for(let i = 0; i < usersConnections.length; i++){

            if(
                usersConnections[i].username == data.username && 
                usersConnections[i].type_user == data.type_user){

                console.log("yes!");
                io.to(usersConnections[i].ID).emit('subject', 
                    {from: {nick: socket.nickname, typeU: socket.type_user, location: socket.location}, sended: new Date()}
                );
                break;

            }

        }

    });

    socket.on('confirm-invitation', (isConfirmed)=>{

        io.emit('newRoom', {confirmed: isConfirmed, 
            from: {nick: socket.nickname, typeU: socket.type_user}}
        );

    });

    socket.on('add-message', (message)=>{

        io.emit('message', {text: message.text, from: socket.nickname, created: new Date()});

    });

});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

http.listen(PORT, ()=>{

    console.log(`Socket server listening in: http://localhost:${PORT}`);

});
```

en el app.module.ts tengo:

```
import {NgPipesModule} from 'ngx-pipes';
import { SocketIoModule, SocketIoConfig } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';

const config: SocketIoConfig = {url: `${GLOBAL_SERVER}:3001`, options: {}};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, SelectUsersModalPage],
  entryComponents: [SelectUsersModalPage],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgPipesModule,
    SocketIoModule.forRoot(config),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    PostProvider,
    Camera,
    Geolocation,
    GoogleMaps,
    LocalNotifications,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]

})
export class AppModule {}
```

y para no extender mucho el código, la forma en la que me conecto al socket server en la pagina donde uso el socket es esta:

select-users-modal.page.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { getUsersDistance } from '../../global_modules/locationTreating';
import { removeASingleFromArray } from '../../global_modules/globalFunctions';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-users-modal',
  templateUrl: './select-users-modal.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-users-modal.page.scss'],
})

export class SelectUsersModalPage implements OnInit {

  public selectedUsers = [];
  public absOnlineUsers = [];
  public onlineUsers = [];
  public actualGeoLocation;
  public userData;

  private randomContent = [
        'Sneaky little hobbitses!',
        "Go back, Sam! I'm going to Mordor alone!",
        "What we need is a few good taters.",
        "Also i need a burger, let's pick one up!",
        "I have hunger!, let me food!"
  ];

  constructor(private socket: Socket, geolocation: Geolocation){

    this.getConnections().subscribe((data) =>{

      switch(data['event']){

        case 'joined':

          this.onlineUsers = this.onlineUsers.concat([data]);
          this.absOnlineUsers = getUsersDistance(this.actualGeoLocation, this.onlineUsers);
          break;

        default:

          this.onlineUsers = removeASingleFromArray(this.onlineUsers, data['index']);
          this.absOnlineUsers = removeASingleFromArray(this.absOnlineUsers, data['index']);
          break;

      }

    });

  }

  private async getActualGeoPosition() {
      const rta = await this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      return {
       lat: rta.coords.latitude,
       lng: rta.coords.longitude
      };
  }

  getConnections(){

    let observable = new Observable(observer =>{

      this.socket.on("users-changed", data =>{

        observer.next(data);

      });

    });

    return observable;

  }

  ionViewWillEnter(){

      this.setup();

  }

  async setup(){

       this.userData = await this.getUserData();
       this.actualGeoLocation = await this.getActualGeoPosition();
       this.setSocConnection();

  }

  async setSocConnection(){

    this.userData = await this.getUserData();
    this.actualGeoLocation = await this.getActualGeoPosition();
    this.socket.connect();
    this.socket.emit('set-nickname', 
      {
        nickname: this.userData.data.username, type_user: this.userData.data.type_user,
        src: this.defaultAvatarImage, //cambiar a una url si se desea
        description: this.randomContent[Math.random() * this.randomContent.length | 0],
        location: this.actualGeoLocation
      }
    );

  }

  async getUserData(){

      //session storage = {data: {username: '', type_user: ''}}
      return await this.storage.get('session_storage');

  }

  ionViewWillLeave(){

      this.socket.disconnect();

  }

}
```

las funciones que se importan llamadas getUserDistance y remove a single fromArray se ven asi:

```
export function removeASingleFromArray(arr, index){

    let firstPart = arr.slice(0, index < 0 ? 0 : index);
    let secondPart = index < arr.length ? arr.slice(index + 1): null;
    let transformedArr = secondPart ? firstPart.concat(secondPart) : firstPart;

    return transformedArr;
}

export function getUsersDistance(userLocation, locations){

    return locations.map(loc => {
        const latDiff = Math.abs(userLocation.lat - loc.lat);
        const lngDiff = Math.abs(userLocation.lng - loc.lng);
        const diff = latDiff + lngDiff;
        return {
            src: loc.src,
            name: loc.name,
            description: loc.description,
            isChecked: loc.isChecked,
            location: {
                lat: latDiff, lng: lngDiff, diff
            },
            event: loc.event
        };
    });

}
```

la constante GLOBAL_SERVER se ve asi:

```
export const GLOBAL_SERVER = "http://192.168.1.178";
```

Lo que tiene que pasar es que al momento de yo abrir la app en el cel en ese tab se tiene que hacer una conexion al socket, cosa que me realiza bien cuando lo hago desde el pc y puedo realizar tantas conexiones yo quiera, pero cuando lo intento realizar en el telefono no pasa absolutamente nada... como ultimo dejo parte del html de la pagina select-users-modal.page.html:

```
<ion-header translucent>
  <ion-toolbar class = "selectUsersToolbar">

    <!-- Ciert contenido irrelevante... -->

  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content fullscreen>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item lines = "inset" class = "usersItem unselectedItem" 
    *ngFor = "let onlineUser of absOnlineUsers | orderBy: ['location.diff'];">
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img [src]="onlineUser.src"><!-- cambiar si se desea a una url -->
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label>
        <h2>{{onlineUser.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{onlineUser.description}}</p>
      </ion-label>
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Por ejemplo si yo me meto a la app desde el celular, al momento de realizarse la conexion (si se realizara), y luego yo por ejemplo desde mi pc intente hacer otra conexion desde mi pc al socket, como resultado a mi celular le debería aparecer un nuevo usuario en la lista, cosa que no es así... es mas, el servidor socket nisiquiera detecta alguna conexión al servidor desde mi android... y cuando uno de los dos esta conectado e intento conectar desde otro dispositivo, en mi caso (mi celular y el pc), el server no detecta ni las conexiones del celular, ni las del pc cuando me desconecto del socket y vuelvo a conectarme...

Comment: Me asegure en las pruebas de que ambos dispositivos estan usando la misma conexion wifi, por lo que... si, ambos estan conectados a la misma red y estan usando la red wifi, no estan usando ethernet ni nada (es mas lo deshabilite desde el pc el ethernet). aunque antes de eso igual no funcionaba.

Comment: Lo preguntaba sobre todo por el móvil, pero ya he leído con mas calma y he descartado eso. No tengo experiencia con `socket.io`, pero para ir descartando ¿ puedes conectar 2 clientes simultaneos desde el PC ? ¿ Funciona bien en ese caso ?

Comment: conectar dos clientes SOLO desde el pc, funciona de manera perfecta en ese caso, aunque yo lo que hago es abrir dos pestañas, una normal y otra de incognito, ya que si las dos instancias de las ventanas las reconoce como las mismas pero en diferente pestaña, se me cambia el usuario en ambas, (cosa que no deseo), por lo que inicio sesion en el normal, y abro una ventana incognito e inicio sesion con otro usuario y de esta manera puedo conectar de manera perfecta ambos sockets con el server.

Comment: Bueno, pues creo que eso ya descarta el problema en Node ... o, al menos, el problema principal. Te toca esperar a algún experto en `Ionic` :-(

Comment: Gracias de todas formas :3, aunque ionic practicamente es angular, mas bien tocaria esperar un experto en angular, como dato curioso, esto me funciona bien solo en chrome, en mozilla firefox no me detecta conexion con el socket...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estuve revisando mi código y realmente no encontre nada extraño ni de parte del cliente ni de parte del server, sin embargo seguia aun sin realizarse me la conexion de manera correcta desde el celular, por lo que ayer estuve colocando muchos console.log de ahi por alla y me di cuenta de algo:

Nunca se estaba ejecutando la función de conexion al server desde el celular y algunas otras!, la razón por la que funcionaba en el pc pero no funcionaba en el celular es que ya habia dado permisos de ubicación desde el pc y los habia guardado, por lo tanto obtenia la geolocalización del cliente y ejecutaba DESPUES, de que la ubicación hubiese sido obtenida, ejecutaba las demás funciones, era precisamente este el problema!

lo que pasa es que las funciones como:

```
getUserData
getActualGeoPosition
```

las hice asincronas, el resultado de esto es que hasta que las dos no sean ejecutadas de manera satisfactoria o sean rechazadas, no va a ejecutar la tercera linea, que es la conexion con el socket:

```
setSocConnection
```

Y yo no tenia activada la ubicación desde el telefono cuando intentaba ejecutar la conexión, por esta razón la función que obtiene la ubicación nunca se resolvia o rechazaba, de manera que active la ubicación del telefono y funcionó!, era que nunca se llegaba a la parte de la conexion con el socket en el telefono por que la ubicación nunca se resolvia...